# Wrap text around printed php variable

Tags: php, drupal

I'm struggling to find an answer on how to add text on the same line as a printed php variable in my Drupal site. It has to be incredibly easy, but i'm learning. When I type

```
Time:<?php print render($content['field_duration']); ?>minutes
```

I get:

```
Time:
5
minutes
```

Anyway to get it to be "Time: 5 minutes"?

Comment: I'm going to wager that `render()` returns a string wrapped in a block-level HTML element, like a `p` or a `div`.  Not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure.

Comment: Yep. Just as Charles pointed out, a block level element is being returned back. Posting `render()` code would help

Comment: @asprin can you elaborate? I thought I was posting the render() code.

Comment: I meant posting the `function render()` code

Comment: Can you shoot me the code please? I am not having much luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it'll be easier to solve that with css or without render().

With CSS something like this:

```
<style>
  #text, #time {
   float: left;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <div id="text">Time: </div>
  <div id="time">
    <?php print render($content['field_duration']); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

And without render() - just to output `$content['your_field']` on your own. `var_dump()` this variable to be sure what data it contains, and then `echo` this data directly (via `foreach` if it's an array). I hope it should work just fine.

Comment: In the end that worked the best for me since I am more familiar with CSS. Floating them both left did the trick. Thanks @tulvit.

Answer (score 2):

How about just putting the constant strings in the PHP?

```
<?php print render($dur = 'Time: ' . implode($content['field_duration']) . ' minutes'); ?>
```

The render function takes arguments by reference, so the string must be stored in a variable. The implode function makes the array a string.

Comment: Unfortunately, that breaks my page. So no luck.

Comment: I don't get any syntax errors, but it completely destroys my webpage layout. All formatting is lost and most of the text along with it.

Comment: Getting closer! That output: "Time: Array minutes"

Comment: How about that? I assume $content['field_duration'] is an array, so just take whichever value from it that you want.

Comment: Yeah it is an array, but when I change it away from '0' it doesn't give any value.

Comment: Then it's just an array with only 1 element

Comment: Yeah, true. '$content' has multiple elements and 'field_duration' is one of those.

Comment: Right, and field_duration is also an array, but it only has 1 element. So I assume this code does give you the correct result?

Comment: No, it gives me "Time: Array minutes" still.

Comment: Alright, I'll try again then. Unfortunately, without more information I'm somewhat guessing here. If that doesn't work, can you post print_r($content['field_duration']) ?

Answer (score 1):

A more 'Drupal' way to do it:

```
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_duration');

echo 'Time: ' . $field_items[0]['value'] . ' minutes';
```

You'd be better off putting this in a preprocess function and passing the variable through to the template file rather than doing it in there directly, but the logic should work wherever you put it.

Comment: Thanks Clive, could you elaborate a bit more exactly what I would type. I just don't know enough php. When I place this in PHP tags it doesn't work. I like the idea of passing it through the template file, but then how would I call it in the node template file?

Answer (score 0):

Try

<?php print render( "Time:{$content['field_duration']} minutes "); ?>

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for trying! But that doesn't work either. I get the same broken formatting as @Clukester gave.

Comment: where does **$content['field_duration']** come from?

Comment: It's coming from a custom field that I created in a Drupal content type. The custom field is 'field_duration" Seeing that its in node.tpl.php it is wrapped in two <div> tags so maybe that is the case? I'm not sure if the render() is causing the blocking or it's those div's.

Comment: that's the likely problem; you have wrapped the **field_duration** in a block statement;